# Use Vincenty Ellipsoid distance as custom metric in Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: r, gis, dijkstra

I am thinking of measuring the length of an edge connecting two vertices as their great circle distance, using the Vincenty Ellipsoid distance function in `geosphere`, then later finding the shortest path/route from one location to the next using Dijkstra's algorithm, which I can do via `shortestPath()` in `gdistance` or `shortest_paths()` in `igraph`.

Here are the steps I am taking in R:

1. Create a graph with vertices and edges, where vertices are worldwide points ~100km from the nearest 4 neighbors, are on land only, and are above sea level and under 2000m elevation
2. Calculate edge weights as great circle distances using `distVincentyEllipsoid()`
3. Create a distance table to keep track of the minimum distance from the source node to each node
4. Modify Dijkstra's Algorithm so that in the main loop of Dijkstra's algorithm, when considering neighboring nodes of the current node I use the great circle distance (step 2) as the weight of the edge when calculating tentative distances and update the distance table
5. After Dijkstra's algorithm, use the distance table to find the shortest path from the source location to the destination location

I am having trouble with Step 4 in that I am unsure how to modify the algorithm?

For example, if the `igraph` example

```
shortest_paths(
  graph,
  from,
  to = V(graph),
  mode = c("out", "all", "in"),
  weights = NULL,
  output = c("vpath", "epath", "both"),
  predecessors = FALSE,
  inbound.edges = FALSE,
  algorithm = c("automatic", "unweighted", "dijkstra", "bellman-ford")
)
```

Are my edge weights as great circle distances using the `distVincentyEllipsoid()` function from Step 3 what serve as the `weights` argument in the `shortest_paths()` function in `igraph`?

I am not confident I am understanding the execution of the Dijkstra's algorithm.

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Mark How is that edit?

Comment: It's unclear to me if indeed the gdistance and igraph questions are two separate questions. If they are, then I'd suggest splitting one off and making it it's own question

Comment: @Mark Thanks for editing. My confusion arises when comparing the documentation for the ```gdistance``` and ```igraph``` packages. I am not clear on whether you compute your distances and then use them to find your paths (which I thought was the case), and if that is the case whether the Dijkstra's algorithm is both a distance measure and a path measure? Then how do I incorporate great circle distances?

Comment: I don't know if I follow. What do you mean by distance measure versus path measure. Can you elaborate? Do you mean in the case of distance measure, the path the crow flies?

Comment: @Mark Sure, the first sentence of the ```gdistance``` vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/Overview.html states, "The R package gdistance provides classes and functions to calculate various distance measures and routes in heterogeneous geographic spaces represented as grids." In R I would like to set the length of an edge connecting two vertices as their great circle Vincenty Ellipsoid distance, and then I would like to find the shortest path from location A to location B using the Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @Mark  I thought these were two steps: Use ```geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid()``` and then use ```gdistance::shortestPath()``` or ```gdistance::costDistance()```. However, ```shortestPath()``` and ```costDistance()``` take Long/Lat as input and do not let me specify my vertices with great circle distances between them. Further, ```igraph``` package employs the Dijkstra's algorithm in their ```distances()``` function, again with no way for me to specify the great circle distances to go into the Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: I don't know if you answered my question, but thank you for sharing that. We'll see if someone comes along to answer. If not, I'll post a bounty on it

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I appreciate that support. I will continue to research these two concepts to see if I can even improve my communication of my confusion. I guess that's how confused I am!

Comment: @Mark I (hopefully) improved on the text of the question with more specifics requesting help with implementation in the hopes through that any theory issues will come to light.

Comment: you might find this useful: https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html

Comment: @Mark I am not sure where to go from here with no additional answers. What do you suggest?

Comment: hi simpson! it's sad, I thought there would be more interest :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with vincenty but I can speak to Dijkstra. Dijkstra is just a way of navigating a weighted graph. So in a way, specifying Dijkstra seems to be a bit beside the point here, because the real issue is creating a weighted graph

Comment: if you can create a weighted graph, then you could use Dijkstra, or any other algorithm to try and solve it. The weights can be anything, but maybe in this case you want them to be the distance using vincenty

Comment: @Mark Yes, the weights I am hoping to be a combination of elevation and Vincenty Ellipsoid distance. What do you mean by "specifying Dijkstra seems to be a bit beside the point here"?

Comment: well, Dijkstra is a way of navigating a graph, and Vincenty is a method of calculating distances between points, so they seem to be distinct things

Comment: an analogy would be, Dijkstra is like a set of rules for navigating a labyrinth, and Vincenty is a way of measuring the distance from point a to point b. Distances and rules are separate things

Comment: @Mark Okay, this is helpful. I guess I don't understand how the shortest path does not incorporate distance necessarily? For example, if I navigate the labyrinth from two different start points, and I want to know which of the two is the shortest path, wouldn't it make sense to evaluate the shortest path via the least distance?

Comment: well, distance is one method for determining cost. Imagine a city with lots of hills, like San Francisco. The shortest way of getting to a place for as the bird flies might not be the fastest for a human on foot

Comment: Or think of two cities, connected by high speed trains or planes, but with extremely slow public transport within their respective cities.

Comment: The general idea is that of the *cost* of moving from one place to another. That could be the distance (calculated any way you wish), or that could be the time, or the fuel costs, or some combination of those things with other things.

Comment: Once you have that, you can abstract away all of the details and work with a simple graph, a network of nodes and edges. And that is the point at which you use Dijkstra. See this gif: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Dijkstra_Animation.gif

Comment: @Mark, So I can attribute the cost of traveling throughout hilly San Francisco to a combination of elevation and the distance to help compute the shortest path as per the gif you shared that I stared at for ten minutes?

Comment: hahaha, it's quite mesmerising! yeah exactly. That would be a good approach for that problem. Then you may incorporate things the costs of travelling across bridges and such, because San Francisco is on a bay. e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/dir/37.9834057,-122.4520768/Point+San+Pablo,+Richmond,+CA+94801,+USA/@37.9566283,-122.5347456,11.81z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x80859c60e2f634a5:0xea7b07fe89b4584a!2m2!1d-122.4276133!2d37.9640786!3e0?entry=ttu

Comment: the point is that once you decide on a cost function, you can then apply that to the paths through the labyrinth (or roads in a city), each forking path being one of the dots on the gif

Comment: is it starting to make sense now?

Comment: @Mark Yes, the theory is making sense now. When you say work with a simple graph that is a network of nodes and edges, I am thinking that the nodes are locations that have elevation and that the edges that connect the nodes can be the distances? In this way I can find the shortest path between two locations (that encompass multiple nodes)? Where does the cost 'function' come into play?